# pass params from one page to another in angular ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to pass params from signup page to signupotp page. In my signupotp page otp is not getting recognised because of the params (email and mobile)is not getting passed to signupotp page. My backedn is coded like for otp verification params (mobile,emaail,otp) should be verified.So its not getting working properly . I tried to initialise my data in signup page and passed to signupotp page.But not working. How to do this?

SIGNUP.PAGE.TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ApiService} from '../api.service';
import{Router} from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {SignupotpPage} from '../signupotp/signupotp.page';

@Component({
selector: 'app-signup',
templateUrl: './signup.page.html',
styleUrls: ['./signup.page.scss'],
})
export class SignupPage implements OnInit {

Mobile:any;
Email:any;
data:any;
otp:any;
checked:any;


constructor(private api:ApiService,private router:Router,public signupotp:SignupotpPage) {}

ngOnInit() {
}

Continue(Mobile,Email){
const user= {
Mobile:Mobile,
  Email:Email
}
console.log(Mobile);
console.log(Email);

this.api.SignupUser(user).subscribe(data=>{
console.log(data);
this.signupotp.initialisedata(Mobile,Email);
this.router.navigate(['signupotp']);

});
}
}
```

SIGNUPOTP.PAGE.TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ApiService} from '../api.service';
import{Router} from '@angular/router';
@Component({
selector: 'app-signupotp',
templateUrl: './signupotp.page.html',
styleUrls: ['./signupotp.page.scss'],
})
export class SignupotpPage implements OnInit {

Mobile:any;
Email:any;
otp:any;
data:any;

constructor(private api:ApiService,private router:Router) {


}
initialisedata(email,mobile)
{
console.log("HUUUU");
console.log(email,mobile);
this.Email = email;
this.Mobile = mobile; 
}
ngOnInit() {
}



Confirm(otp){
const user= {
otp:otp,
mobile:this.Mobile,
email:this.Email
}
console.log(otp); 
console.log("hey how are you")


this.api.Verifysignupotp(user).subscribe(data=>{
console.log(data);
this.data =  data;
if(this.data.Msg)
{
alert(this.data.Msg);
}
else
{
this.router.navigate(['/']);
}

});
}
}
```

Service.ts

```
SignupUser(user):Observable<Object>{
console.log(user);

console.log('getting the signup data from user');
return this.http.post<Object>(`${this.base_url}/signup`,user);

}

 Verifysignupotp(user): Observable<Object>{
    console.log(user);
    console.log('getting all Listing from the server');
    return this.http.post<Object>(`${this.base_url}/verifysignupotp`,user);
  }
```

Comment: you can use Events Library for Real Time Update. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57360460/5909026

Answer (score 0):

There are ways in angular to pass parameters over the url of the route like this: `this.router.navigate[‚path‘, param]`
In your app-routing.module.ts you have to write something like this:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'path/:param', component: yourComponent }
];
```

Or you just write the parameters on some variables in your signup Service and read them from wherever you want to use them.

In your case I would create a object called `user` in your service.ts.
When you get the data in your signup Component/Page you write it on the `user` Object at your service.ts
After navigating to your singupotp Page/Component you can read the data from the service and maybe extend the object with some other data.

Comment: Maybe it‘s important to know, that when you pass the Params over the routes all data can be seen in plain text in the url

Comment: No components for ionic .Page is using in ionic. How to do this in ionic

Comment: You still use components in Ionic even if they are named page. Anyway the navigation over Routing works the same and the strategy with the service doesn‘t depend on if its a component or something different

Comment: I am working on an Ionic project at the Moment and for communication between components I prefer using services in combination with rxjs Observables

Comment: I want to pass the Email and Mobile to OTP page to verifying.But it's showing error

Comment: Can you explain the way to passing the params to otp page and verify it

Comment: As I understand you get the EMail and Mobile data in your signup Component/Page and you want to navigate to your signupotp Component/page and then youse the same data there. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Yes I am getting the data in the console when inputing email and mobile and then navigate it to the otp page. But there i cant get the email and mobile along with otp on console.

Comment: I want to match otp , mobile and email