# Ionic 4 Events not working in device but working on browser

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using `"@ionic/angular": "^4.11.10"`

I'm trying to display the tabs in `ion-tabs` in `ion-tab-bar` depending on whether an event was emitted. I have an `*ngIf` for conditional rendering. Here's the code:

```
<ion-tabs color="danger">
    <ion-tab-bar class="tab-bar" slot="bottom">
        <ion-tab-button *ngIf="!registerClicked" tab="tab1">
            <ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>{{'Transfer' | translate}}</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>

        <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
            <ion-icon name="gift"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>{{'Perks' | translate}}</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>
<ion-tabs>
```

Here's the event emitter:

```
import { Events } from '@ionic/angular';
export class LoginModalPage 
  constructor(
      public event:Events
    ) { }

  public login() {
      this.event.publish('registerClicked', false);
  }
}
```

Similarly, there is another function that sets registerClicked to true:

```
import { Events } from '@ionic/angular';
export class RegisterModalPage 
  constructor(
      public event:Events
    ) { }

  public register() {
      this.event.publish('registerClicked', true);
  }
}
```

and in the code behind for the tabs,

```
import { Events } from '@ionic/angular';
export class TabsPage {
  public registerClicked:boolean;
  constructor(
    public event: Events
  ) {
    this.event.subscribe('registerClicked', (data) =>{
      this.registerClicked = data;
    });
  }
}
```

Now the code is working as expected when I run localhost:4200, the `tab1` is displayed when the login function is called on button click and the tab is not visible when I click a button that executes the `register()` function. However when I build an apk, and test it on a device, this doesn't work. Can anyone provide any insight into accomplishing this?

Comment: `Events` are not supported anymore in Ionic. use  observable.

Comment: I'm using ionic 4

Comment: Still go for the solution i posted in my answer.

Comment: you can also use BehaviourSubject.. slightly better alternative to simple Subjects.

Comment: Another alternative can be found **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64908617/3915438)**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To update Data from one page to other we used Events library. but events are no longer available in ionic 5.
blow is the solution. 
run command:

```
ionic generate service events        // this will create events provider
```

copy paste blow code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EventsService {

private fooSubject = new Subject<any>();

constructor() { }


    publishLogin(data: any) {
        this.fooSubject.next(data);
    }

    receiveLogin(): Subject<any> {
        return this.fooSubject;
    }
}
```

From Page A:
import your service
initialize it in constructor //

```
constructor(public events: EventsService){}
```

and publish event E.g.

```
 this.events.publishLogin(yourDataVariable);
```

Receive it in Page B:
import your service
initialize it in constructor //

```
    constructor(public events: EventsService){}

this.events.receiveLogin().subscribe((res:any)=>{
        console.log(res);
      })
```

Comment: I'll have a look shortly

Comment: is the `this.events.receiveLogin()...` supposed to be in the constructor?

Comment: I added it in ngOnInit

Comment: Yes, you can add it in `constructor`

Comment: Thats fine. no issues

Comment: Okay, as usual, it works in the browser but now I'm building the app, I'll let you know if it works on the app...

Comment: Let me know the Result.

Comment: glad to hear that.