# Searching alternative for events in ionic 5

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic5

Ionic 4 Components:

```
import {Events} from '@ionic/angular';

 constructor(private auth: AuthService, private events: Events) {}




intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
     
 // Refresh token failed, logout user
    this.events.publish('user:logout', 'La sesión ha expirado');
    
    }
```

In Ionic 5 events are removed...
How i need to chnage w.t.t ionic5 ..Pls let me know

```
EDIT ::



 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
    
    @Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
    
    export class EventService{
      private formRefreshAnnouncedSource = new Subject();
      formRefreshSource$ = this.formRefreshAnnouncedSource.asObservable();
    
      publishFormRefresh(){
        this.formRefreshAnnouncedSource.next()
      }
    
    }
```

How to add parameter this event service?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ionic 4 Events not working in device but working on browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62275082/ionic-4-events-not-working-in-device-but-working-on-browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build your own "events service" by using a subject behind the scenes:

```
// app-events.enum.ts

export enum AppEvent {
  UserLogout = 'UserLogout',
  // ...
}
```

```
// app-events.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AppEvent } from '../enums/app-event.enum';

interface EventDetails {
  event: AppEvent;
  payload?: unknown;
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AppEventsService {
  private eventsDispatcher = new Subject<EventDetails>();

  public dispatch(event: AppEvent, payload?: unknown): void {
    this.eventsDispatcher.next({ event, payload });
  }

  public onEvent(event: AppEvent): Observable<unknown> {
    return this.eventsDispatcher.asObservable().pipe(
      filter((eventDetails) => eventDetails.event === event),
      map((eventDetails) => eventDetails.payload),
    );
  }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
// dispatch
this.appEventsService.dispatch(AppEvent.UserLogout, 'La sesión ha expirado');

// listen to events
this.appEventsService
    .onEvent(AppEvent.UserLogout)
    .subscribe((message: string) => {
      console.log(message);
    });
```

I'm sure this could be improved if you need better support for types in the payload but it should be more than enough to replace Ionic Events as it used to work Ionic 3.

Comment: Thnk you very much fr help..i m new to ionic,..

Comment: Sir, actually I I need to call logout ...I have user logout button in view and method in  login.ts file ...can u pls let me know how I can be used events to logout when like refresh token expired. Thanks

Comment: @Ajt Sure! Could you please create a Stackblitz demo with your code? You can use **[this starter](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-starter-app)** if you want :)

Answer (score 1):

First give the Subject a type, then pass a parameter(s) when you call next(), like so:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})

export class EventService{
  private formRefreshAnnouncedSource = new Subject<string>();
  formRefreshSource$ = this.formRefreshAnnouncedSource.asObservable();

  publishFormRefresh(eventName: string){
    this.formRefreshAnnouncedSource.next(eventName)
  }

}
```