# ionic 5 network connectivity issues api handling

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I am searching for a better solution to popup dialog with connection fail if the internet is off at any position of my app.

Option 1 is too check connection activity in app.component.ts and show/hide modalpopup there.
But there is situation where some reference value coming from last page, then new page modal will comes if internet now available but the API which should be fire is dead.

For API even I can handle with each page check function after model close but then opening and closing modal should happens in each page.

But I need a globle function to handle this.

thanks

Comment: User `Observables` to check if Internet is back. Have a look at this to get an Idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62275436/5909026

Comment: Yes this way need to handle in each page, can't we make any global handler for api calls ?