# how to auto-refresh a page in Ionic/Angular

Tags: ionic-framework

I try to make an application with ionic but I get this problem:
for example, the application has two pages, the first one has the name of the user, and the second one I can change his name there.
If I change the name on the second page and go back to the president page (page 1) I get the old name (before the changes)

I want to know how to auto-refresh and page for another without any action from the user when I click the  go back button

I do some search and I get only two solutions for this problem:

1. use ion-refresher  (the problem with this solution the user must do an action (pull down to refresh))
2. I see some people use clear cache view ( but this solution I don't get any information on how to use it with ionic 6, at the same time I'm not using ionic view I'm using Angular)

sorry for my bad English but may this video can explain more: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HExPUfuaRwU&ab_channel=www.codeandyou.comwww.codeandyou.com

please help

Comment: When you want to go to the second page ,don't use routerLink use router is typescript and write a function that redirect you to the second page using replaceUrl:true, in this way the first page will be overwritten and when you go back to it the page will reload from the beginning

Comment: OK, friend, I miss this solution because I use `ion-back-button`, I think if I change it to a simple button with a function will solve the problem  thank you very much

Comment: did I must use `this.roote.navigate(['pageURL']);` ?? in the function ? to make the overwritten to the page 1

Comment: you can use navController.navigateRoot('pageUrl')

Comment: thank you friend I try it and it's work with me

Comment: Also you can do Something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62275436/5909026

Answer (score 0):

Call the function to load the name from `ionViewWillEnter`.

Ionic pages have a lifecycle. Since you're using angular, you can refer here https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle. In the page, it says

`ionViewWillEnter - Since ionViewWillEnter is called every time the view is navigated to (regardless if initialized or not), it's a good method to load data from services.`

I faced the same problem as you, and now I just put the needed function to load the data inside `ionViewWillEnter`. For example

```
export class TabCloseContactsPage implements OnInit {
    async ngOnInit() {
        await this.storage.create();
    }

    async ionViewWillEnter (){
        functionThatShouldBeCalledEveryTimeThisPageIsDisplayed()
    }
}
```