# How to pass data to another page from Input Form in IONIC 5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I have an input form with **3 text input**. The only thing i want it is to send this 3 datas to another page that i called "Identity". I'd like to know how can do to send this 3 datas to another page using ionic 5. **I want to create a signing step by step style**. someone can help please?

**REGISTER.PAGE.HTML**

```
  <ion-content fullscreen="true" class="background-contact">
    <div class="fixed">
      
      <div class="div-3">
            <div align="center">
              <b>IDENTIFICATION</b>
            </div>
  
            <ion-label position="stacked" class="title">E-mail</ion-label>
            <div align="center" class="input-class">
              <ion-input autofocus="true" ngModel  name="email" type="email" placeholder="informez votre email"></ion-input>
            </div> 
        
            <div class="line">
              <ion-label position="stacked" class="title">Mot de passe</ion-label>
              <div align="center" class="input-class">
                <ion-input ngModel name="password" type="password" placeholder="informez votre mot de passe"></ion-input>
              </div>
            </div>
  
            <!-- <div class="line">
              <ion-label position="stacked" class="title">Téléphone</ion-label>
              <div align="center" class="input-class">
                <ion-input autofocus="true" ngModel name="phone" type="text"  placeholder="Tapez votre numéro de tel" (keypress)="numberOnlyValidation($event)"></ion-input>
              </div>
            </div> -->
  
            <div class="line">
              <ion-label position="stacked" class="title">Pays</ion-label>
              <div align="center" >
                <ion-select  cancelText="Fermer" okText="Confirmer" ngModel name="cod_country">
                  <ion-select-option value="">Dans quel pays êtes-vous?</ion-select-option>
                    <ion-select-option value="{{item?.id}}" *ngFor="let item of country">{{item?.name}}</ion-select-option>
                </ion-select>
              </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="line">
              <div align="center" class="input-class">
                <ion-button  (click)="goToAboutPage()"  expand="block" color="primary"><ion-spinner *ngIf="loading"></ion-spinner> CONFIRMER <ion-icon name="checkmark-done"></ion-icon></ion-button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
```

**RESGISTER.PAGE.TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController, NavController, ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { AlertService } from 'src/app/services/alert.service';
import {IdentityPage} from 'src/app/identity/identity.page';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.page.scss'],
})
export class RegisterPage implements OnInit {
  loading: boolean;// loading chamando
  country: any;
  password:any;
  private cod_country;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private alertService: AlertService,
    public alertController: AlertController,
    private toast: ToastController,
    private router: Router,
 
  ) { 
     this.getCountry();
  }

  
  ngOnInit() {
  }

 //Get all country list
  getCountry(){
    this.authService.getCountry().subscribe(country=>{
      this.country = country;
    
    })
  } 

  // navigate to about page
  goToAboutPage(data) {
    this.router.navigate(['/identity'],{
      queryParams:data
    })
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are Multiple Ways to pass data from 1 page to other page.
Method 1:

Use `Angular Router with params`

`Page 1:`

```
goToNewPage(){
 this.router.navigate(['/identity'],{
   queryParams: JSON.Stringify(data)
 })
}
```

`Page 2:`

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params)
  });
}
```

Method 2:

Create a `GlobalDataProviderService`.
Run Command:

> ionic generate service globaldata

inside Globaldata class:

`public static userObject:any;`

Import this class on your both pages and initialize your variable.

`Page 1:`

```
goToNewPage(){
    GlobaldataService.userObject = YourData;
    this.router.navigate(['/identity'])
}
```

`Page 2:`

import this class:

inside Constructor or lifeCycle Hook.

```
yourVaribale = GlobaldataService.usrObject;
```

Method 3 for Real time Update:

Check my Other Answer: [Real Time Data Update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62275436/5909026)

Comment: yourVaribale = GlobaldataService.usrObject; i did not understand. what variable? i have to create one? like const getData = GlobaldataService.usreObject;  ??

Comment: Depends on your Requirements. If you want to use `GlobaldataService` directly you can use it.

Comment: in the first exemple do i need to import something? i am new in IONIC so i'm learning yet. So please i need help. based on the firs answer i am having an undefined return of params. so i wonder if my html is correct...

Comment: in Method 1 you have to import `ActivatedRoute` on 2nd page where you receiving data.

Answer (score 0):

`Page 1 html code`

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col size="12">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="stacked">E-Mail</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="email" [(ngModel)]="email"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="stacked">Password</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Country</ion-label>
        <ion-select placeholder="Select Country" [(ngModel)]="country">
          <ion-select-option value="India">India</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value="Usa">Usa</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="12" class="ion-text-center">
      <ion-button (click)="goToAboutPage()" expand="block" shape="round">
        Click me
      </ion-button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

`Page 1 ts code`

```
public country: string;
  public email: string;
  public password: string;   

constructor(public nav: NavController) {}

goToAboutPage() {
    let params: any = {
      country: this.country,
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password
    }
    this.nav.navigateForward('/identity', { state: params }); // params to pass object/array
  }
```

`Page 2`

```
constructor(public router: Router){
if (router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
      const params = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state;
console.log(params.email)
console.log(params.password)
console.log(params.country) 
    }
}
```

Comment: in your exemplo: this.nav.navigateForward('/identity', { state: params }) how do i pass many params please? i got in my exemple 3 params to pass: country, email and password.

Comment: @wonderCode i update my answer please check

Comment: thanks for the reply. i follwed step by step what your code, but i got in console.log undefine . wondering if i made an erro on my html? can you tell me why is comming undefine please?

Comment: Oh  please try print "params" what you received in params

Comment: also check this url "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6LmKCSU8eM"

Comment: {country: undefined, email: undefined, password: undefined} This the return i have in cosole.log. i have seen the link video but i still having the same problem. i just want to pass data from my input form  to another page and that seems to be hard :( i need help please

Comment: @wonderCode i am update agian my answer now i added full demo with input type. And in input field i added "ngModel" `ngModel` binding data with two way. so copy my html and ts code and put in your code. if working then modify code related to you

Comment: And I check your code you are not used `password` and `country` in the input type I think that's why you get undefined on the next page. if you check dummy data then `let params: any = { country: 'USA', email: 'demo@email.com', password: 'Password' }` try to pass this params in you code